# OpenId Connect : consent can be on the authentication page?

Tags: openid, openid-connect

In the flow OpenId Connect, the consent page is displayed after an authentication successful. Instead, Is it possible to display the consent on the authentication form ?
Eric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you may combine the two logical steps in a single page but that only works with authentication methods that interact with the user in that same page in a synchronous way (e.g. passwords), it wouldn't work (as straightforward) with 2-factor authentication e.g. using a key/phone in addition to a password.